# Insert a Right image above the image when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to creat when user click once on one or more images. It should display right image above the clicked image.
If user again click on selected image it should remove the right image from clicked image

on click my jquery click event is working but it is not showing right symbol above the image.

My code is

```
<div id="url-i-pr" style="margin: 10px;">

 <span class="url-img">
<img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8957.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin: 2px; position:relative;"></span>
<span class="url-img">
<img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8958.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin: 2px; position:relative;"></span>

 <span class="url-img">
 <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8950.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin: 2px; position:relative;"></span>

<span class="url-img">
 <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8951.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin: 2px; position:relative;"></span></div>
```

jquery

```
 $(document).on('click', '#url-i-pr img', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();
       $(this).addClass('select_img');
       alert('hi');
  });
```

I tried [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/o4ok63dt/)

Answer (score 0):

It's working as intended. Your problem is you're trying to show a background image when there's an image in front, so it'll never display. If you change your css from `color: green;` to `border: 1px solid green`, you'll see it's working.

And if you want to toggle it on click, change `addClass` to `toggleClass`.

eD: There were a number of things wrong with the css, this fiddle should allow you to figure out what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/o4ok63dt/3/

Comment: Yes it is working but not as I want I want to put tick image above the selected image

Comment: Yes seen it is showing above the image. can we put in right top cornor

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @evu does the trick - I'm adding this one in because it refactors the styling into classes and provides an alternative design to the overlay:

### jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/raad/r0hz1f46/3/

### CSS + HTML:

```
<style>
  #url-i-pr {
      margin: 10px;
  }

  .img-container {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 2px;
      border: 2px solid transparent;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }

  #url-i-pr img {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }

  .select_img {
      border: 2px solid black !important;
  }

  .select_img:after {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      content: '✔';
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<div id="url-i-pr">
  <span class="img-container">
    <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8957.jpg" />
  </span>
  <span class="img-container">
    <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8958.jpg" />
  </span>
  <span class="img-container">
    <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8950.jpg" />
  </span>
  <span class="img-container">
    <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/images/picsms/2014/sms-8951.jpg" />
  </span>
</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-container', function (f) {
    f.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('select_img');
});
```